# setAllowedFileTypes changing the file extension

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

On doing `setAllowedFileTypes` on `NSSavePanel` object, the extension set in `nameFieldStringValue` changes to first item I pass in `setAllowedFileTypes` array.

```
[dialog setNameFieldStringValue:@"awesome.docx"];  
NSArray *file_types = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"pdf",@"docx",@"txt"];
[dialog setAllowedFileTypes:file_types];
```

Expected Behaviour:
[image]
Actual Behaviour:
[image]

The [doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nssavepanel/1534419-allowedfiletypes?language=objc) does say that:

> If no extension is given by the user, the first item in the
>   allowedFileTypes array will be used as the extension for the save
>   panel.

But I am providing an extension. Am I missing something here.

Comment: Are you sure the extension is in the array? Did you try `setAllowedFileTypes` first and then `setNameFieldStringValue`? The documentation says "If no extension is given by the **user**" but your code is not the user. If the user types 'Mydocument' and hits the Save button, '.pdf' is added.

Comment: Setting `setAllowedFileTypes` first and then `setNameFieldStringValue` worked.